# When to notify users via email vs onsite

Tags: notification, messages, alerts, chat

We have a system where users will create groups where things will happen at a fast and slow pace. It is important that all users in the group know that updates have been made. Here are the use cases:

1. The user is viewing the group which will update via ajax (no notification is needed)
2. The user is currently in another group but needs to notified
3. The user is offline and needs to be notified via email.

What is the best practice that can be employed to make the UX good for use case number 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it is done on StackExchange is pretty good?
Use a toolbar which runs through all the groups and has a notifications area.

[image: Stack Exchange, notifications]

Comment: I thought that might be the only other answer - thank you